# ReactJS - Can't print out todos, this.props.todos.map not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I am new to react and I'm trying to print out some data from a GET request and print them out but I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: this.props.todos.map is not a function - error.

If I change `this.setState({data: data})` on the success function I can get the data in my console, but is there any quick and simple way to fix this to print the data?

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import $ from 'jquery';
import Todos from "./Components/Todos"


class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos:[]
    }
  }
  getTodos(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'url',
      dataType:'json',
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic " + btoa("username" + ":" + "password")
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
        this.setState({todos: data}, function(){
          console.log(this.state);
        });
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    this.getTodos();
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.getTodos();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Todos todos={this.state.todos}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Todos.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';

class Todos extends Component {
  render() {
    let todoItems;
    if(this.props.todos){

      todoItems = this.props.todos.map(todo => {
        return (
          <TodoItem key={todo.code} todo={todo} />
        );
      });
    }
    return (
      <div className="Todos">
        <h3>Results:</h3>
        {todoItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Todos;
```

**TodoItem.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TodoItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li className="Todo">
        <strong>{this.props.todo.code}</strong>
      </li>
    );
  }
}


export default TodoItem;
```

Snippet from the console log:

[image]

Comment: post console log that you are getting, when you do console.log(this.state);

Comment: can you `console.log(this.state.todos)` inside  App.js

Comment: @Andy this.props.todos is initialised with an empty array in wrapper component. `this.state = {
      todos:[]
    }`  there is not need for null check

Comment: @Andy i've run into this issue many time to the point where i am able to spot it from miles away

Comment: what does the console log print inside the success callback? are you sure that your server is returning an array?

Comment: Obviously server is not returning an array, it must be returning an Object and thats the reason for .map is not a function - error.

Comment: @Subin it also could be undefined when he try to render the element , that why the function map trow an error since he try to render before the state is populated with the respanse

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif it will never be undefined as it is properly initialised in App components constructor.Initial state is an empty array. Initially it will pass in empty array which wont cause any problems . Then his server may return and object he passes it down and second render of Todos throw this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

todos has to be an array always. So change setState like this in your success function.

```
this.setState({todos: (data.resources ? data.resources : [])}, function(){
          console.log(this.state);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing it useless to call `this.getTodos()` twice just call it in the `componentDidMount()` methode, one more thing that you need to be aware of , the component `TodoItem.js` will render no mather the value of `this.props.todo.code` to avoid the issue you need added this into your `TodoItem.js`

```
class TodoItem extends Component {
  render() {
    if(!this.props.todo){
       <div>Loading</div>
      }
    return (
      <li className="Todo">
        <strong>{this.props.todo.code}</strong>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

the `Array.prototype.map()` expect an array so if you try to pass an undefined value to it , it will automatically trow an error wish i believe is the case in your app

one more thing make sur that  `this.state.todo` before trying my solution

Comment: The requested data is inside { } and not in array so this is why I get the error?

Comment: it could also be undefined since you're trying to render before getting the respanse , also added this `this.getTodos = this.getTodos.bind(this)` to your constructor

Answer (score 0):

You also need to bind the `getTodos` function to reference the scope of the class inside it. So bind it inside constructor :

```
this.getTodos = this.getTodos.bind(this)
```

Comment: That wont make a difference as this.getTodos is invoked from componentDidMount(), its not passed as an onClick or onChange. Also callbacks within getTodos are bound to this.